# session variables disappear?

Tags: php, security, session, session-variables, password-encryption

I am trying to learn more about password hashing and secure login, etc. and for that reason I am trying to duplicate [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL) example here. I did not 100% duplicate this.

The problem I encounter is that when I enter my login credentials, the form goes to the `process_login.php` script which verifies the password and so forth, and sets the `$_SESSION` variables. Upon success, it is supposed to redirect to `protected.php`, a site which is only accessible when the user is logged in.

For me it does not work simply because the `$_SESSION` variables disappear!

I am at a point where the `process_login.php` script shows me that `$_SESSION` is set, and then I use `header("Location: protected.php");` which then tells me the `$_SESSION` array is empty. How is this possible? I am missing the boat here...

Here are the parts of the code that are relevant:

**process_login.php**

```
process_login.php

include_once 'connect.php';
include_once 'functions.php';
sec_session_start();

if (isset($_POST['eml'], $_POST['h'])) {
    $email = $_POST['eml'];
    $pwd_hash = $_POST['h'];
    if (login($email, $pwd_hash, $mysqli) == true) {
        // in my situation, this returns true
        // and the redirect to "protected.php" happens
        header('Location: protected.php');
    } else {
        header("Location: error?err=Wrong password");
    }
} else {
    exit('Invalid Request');
}
```

**The `login()` function**

```
function login($email, $password, $mysqli) {
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, email, pwd, salt FROM public WHERE email=? LIMIT 1")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $email, $db_password, $salt);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $password = crypt($password, $salt);
        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            if (checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) == true) {
                // Account is locked 
                $status = "3";
                $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_activity(user, status, ip)
                                VALUES ('$email', '$status', '{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}')");
                sleep(8);
                header("Location: ../error?err=The account you try to access is currently blocked.");
                return false;
            } else {
                // Check if the password in the database matches
                // the password the user submitted.
                if ($db_password == $password) {
                    // Password is correct!
                    // Get the user-agent string of the user.
                    $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                    // XSS protection as we might print this value
                    $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id);
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                    $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512', $password . $user_browser);
                    $status = "1";
                    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_activity (user, status, ip)
                                    VALUES ('{$_SESSION['user_id']}', '$status', '{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}')");
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // Password is not correct
                    // We record this attempt in the database
                    $status = "2";
                    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_activity(user, status, ip)
                                    VALUES ('$email', '$status', '{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}')");
                    sleep(3);
                    header("Location: ../error?err=Password is not correct.");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            // No user exists.
            sleep(2);
            header("Location: ../error?err=No user exists.");
            return false;
        }
        header("Location: ../error?err=You can't see this.");
        return false;
    } else {
        header("Location: ../error?err=DB fail: ".$mysqli->error);
        return false;
    }
}
```

**protected.php**

```
protected.php

<?php
include_once 'connect.php';
include_once 'functions.php';
sec_session_start();
// $return = login_check($mysqli);
print_r(get_defined_vars());
// this outputs an empty $_SESSION array
exit;
```

**function sec_session_start()**

```
function sec_session_start() {
    $session_name = 'sec_session_id';
    $secure = true;
    $httponly = true;
    if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
        header("Location: ../error?err=Could not initiate a safe session (ini_set)");
        exit();
    }
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"],
        $cookieParams["path"], 
        $cookieParams["domain"], 
        $secure,
        $httponly);
    session_name($session_name);
    session_start();
    session_regenerate_id();
}
```

I tried to see what happens if I just start the session using `sec_session_start()` and the following is the result:

```
include_once 'connect.php';
include_once 'functions.php';
sec_session_start();
$_SESSION["test"] = "works!";
header('Location: protected.php');
```

The output from `print_r(get_defined_vars());` in `protected.php` is:

```
[_SESSION] => Array ( )
```

Comment: And what is `sec_session_start()`?

Comment: @Stony I added this function to my question now.

Comment: why do you have sleep? Why is the salt inside the db?  Use the password_hash and password_verify

Comment: @RonniSkansing `sleep()` as additional measure against brute force attacks. Salt is inside DB based on the example from the website I was working with. Not sure if there is a better way to do this. Not sure what else you mentioned. Has this something to do with my question?

Comment: @koljanep no, not really, it is just comment, and might be something to take with you. it does not protect against brute force. The attacker will get correct password just as fast. If there was also sleep on a correct login, it would only delay the attacker 8 sec. The attacker does not need to wait and make sure the password is wrong before trying the next.

Comment: I don't see any immediate reason. What happens if you go through the simplest flow? sec_session_start ,  add something in $_SESSION, redirect and retrieve. Does that work?

Comment: @JeroendeLau I tried that now by creating a new script that simply does `include_once 'connect.php'; include_once 'functions.php'; sec_session_start(); $_SESSION["test"] = "works!"; header('Location: protected.php');`. The `$_SESSION` variable is still empty. Is there something wrong with my session?

Comment: Right, problem seems to be in sec_session_start(); What is SECURE set to in your environment?

Comment: @JeroendeLau `SECURE` isn't set to anything. I did not pay attention to that part, really, but just copied it. I changed it now to `true` as written in the article but it does not resolve the problem. I am going to do an edit now to my question so this data is visible.

Comment: I think the problem is that one of the settings is not allowing the session to be written. I would double check out this function on php, and see how it applies to your environment. http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Answer (score 0):

This may be of help in many session issues. I have used PHP for many years and love it, 
but it is quirky!

In this code -

page1.php

```
<?phpsession_start();?>

<?php
$_SESSION['roman']="kitty";
echo ('<a href="page2.php"> Go To Page 2</a>');
?>
```

page2.php

```
<?php session_start();?>

<?php
echo $_SESSION['roman'];
?>
```

Notice NO space in 'phpsession_start()' on page1, 
but I did use a space in 'php session_start()' on page2.

Using NO space in page2, and the session variables are gone. With a space it works fine. 
In page1, it does not matter, works either way with and without space. I have OTHER scripts where
it is the reverse. Will only work WITHOUT the space! So is something to try and check.

Now many may paste this code and have it work, or not work as I have described, but that is why
it is quirky!